# Ubuntu opening up mulitple udp ports.

Tags: networking, firewall

I have Ubuntu 14 opening many UDP ports. The avadi_daemon was listed as the owner of the process (Using Netstat).  I turned that off, but they then spawned with no owner. I can even kill the process and it starts again using another port.

I don't know what app is doing this.  Is there any way to put some kind of check or rule that says before opening port check?

I am using ufw enabled.

Regards,
Wesley

Comment: Answer is here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/205937/how-can-i-disable-avahi-daemon#206592
From the manpage:
`The  Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon implements Apple's Zeroconf architecture
       (also known as "Rendezvous" or "Bonjour"). The daemon registers  local
       IP  addresses  and  static services using mDNS/DNS-SD and provides two
       IPC APIs for local programs to make use of the mDNS record  cache  the
       avahi-daemon maintains. `
Little bit of search can not harm.

Comment: Thanks, I read that information, but guess I didn't comprehend it.  I just see 6 udp ports  and non-users running       
--WARN-- [lin003w] The process `something' is listening on socket 0t0 (24236 on 
         0t0 interface) is run by 3606. {who is 3606)

Comment: some of the udp are essential for a system to work properly. Each has it's own purpose. You can try to examine what each process does by looking to man pages. Simply `man -k avahi` and it will list up all manpages related to avahi. You can check your running UDP services with the netstat `sudo netstat  -ulpa`. Edit your answer with the output of this command and let us know what you really want to turn off.

Comment: udp        0      0 *:63510                 *:*                                 
5528/dhclient   
udp        0      0 xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-D:domain *:*                                 
1236/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                 
5528/dhclient   
udp        0      0 *:31925                 *:*                                 
3200/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                              
3200/avahi-daemon: 
---

Comment: There are like 4 more that didn't have enough room.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation above provides good information.  After using some investigation the dnsmasq had somehow configured itself to use two mdns servers.  In addition, it looks like I had an uninvited guest.

Another interesting item, if you turn on ufw, you enable the mdns(adding the two mdns servers) and alter you iptables.

ufw -list 
iptables -L
then

ufw enable 
iptables -L.

I tested this on two of my Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14 boxes.

Anyway, ufw modified iptables to allow comm to two mdns servers.

regards,
Wes