# How to get rid of 169.254.0.0 route?

Tags: networking, 16.04, routing

This is from `route -n` command.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.x     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 <wifi>
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 <wifi>
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 <wifi>
```

I have tried:

1) disabled ufw and ran from the terminal(same with ufw enabled):

```
sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0
```

got `SIOCDELRT: Invalid argument`

2) commented `link-local 169.254.0.0` line in the `/etc/networks` file and rebooted.

3) disabled `avahi-deamon` since it seems to be related.

Nothing works, I use static IP but always when I connect to my router and run `route -n command` it appears there. So. do you guys have any other ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the answer below I have looked into `avahi-autoipd` manpage and managed to find a solution. To remove the route:

```
sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev <interface> metric 1000
```

where `<interface>` is your network interface, such as wlan0 for example. However, this would only remove it until next network association because it spawns all over again. So to make it permanent, you need to modify the `/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd` file, the root of the spawning.

I commented out the final part of the code:

```
#if [ -x /bin/ip ]; then
    # route already present?
    #ip route show | grep -q '^169.254.0.0/16[[:space:]]' && exit 0

    #/bin/ip route add 169.254.0.0/16 dev $IFACE metric 1000 scope link
#elif [ -x /sbin/route ]; then
    # route already present?
    #/sbin/route -n | egrep -q "^169.254.0.0[[:space:]]" && exit 0

    #/sbin/route add -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev $IFACE metric 1000
#fi
```

Comment: YES, it works! I only commented out the lines with "route add" and I can confirm: Your solution works fine! (Ubuntu 18.04) Another nice step to clean up the mess in modern Ubuntu ....

Answer (score 13):

There is nothing at all you need to do. The 169.254.0.0 route is typically present for everyone with internet connectivity. Here is the route information from my machine:

```
chili@T440p:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

Please see: https://serverfault.com/questions/132657/where-route-to-169-254-0-0-comes-from

Especially see:

> The 169.254.0.0/16 network is used for Automatic Private IP
>   Addressing, or APIPA. If a DHCP client attempts to get an address, but
>   fails to find a DHCP server after the timeout and retries period it
>   will randomly assume an address from this network. This allows
>   communication with hosts that have failed to obtain a DHCP address.

In short, the entry is entirely normal.

Comment: I do not recall ever having such a route, unless I was having troubles. I checked two of my 16.04 Ubuntu servers just now, both with internet connectivity, and neither has such a route. However, and too my surprise, it is present on my test 16.10 Ubuntu desktop computer.

Comment: ip route on my ubuntu 16.10 box shows: 169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000

Answer (score 2):

You're right in your assumption that this route comes from avahi.

Disabling `avahi-deamon` may not be enough since your DHCP client may be configured to use `avahi-autoipd` in order to set a Link-local IP when the DHCP request fails.

There are several things I would try:

- add a line `deny-interfaces=wifi` (that's the name of your network interface, right?) in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`
- since you're using a static IP anyway, disable your DHCP client (`dhcpcd`?)
- as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/824996/395993) suggests, you can simply uninstall `avahi-daemon`. Sure, this amounts to killing a fly with a steamroller, but it'll work

Comment: First two options didn't work. Third, let's just say I want to keep it as a reserve. But your answer did help me find a solution so cheers for your effort!

Comment: @user633551 You should post your answer as an answer then. I'll be happy to vote it up.

Comment: In 16.04 `avahi-autoipd` is not using `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`, so the first sugestion will not prevent dhcp for calling the `/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd` hook that is part of `avahi-autoipd` package. In my case I even do not have `avahi-daemon` installed.

Comment: in my installation of Ubuntu 18.04 the solution to comment out the "route add" helped;  editing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd    Thanks a lot to user633551.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved like this:

```
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    pre up ip r d 169.254.0.0/16
```

Simply the route gets deleted when network is starting. In Rhel distros it is easy to configure Zeroconf, but I haven't found a way in Debian/Ubuntu. Still, this should do a trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of it all together, worked fine for me on Ubuntu 22:

```
sudo apt-get remove avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon avahi-utils
```

I don't like un-wanted traffic on my network, un-known routes in my ip tables nor services/daemons wasting resources on my system.