# Avahi daemon necessary? CPU load quiet high

Tags: networking, services, avahi

While using htop for some other stuff I noticed a programm called 'avahi-daemon' which is using quiet a lot of my maximum CPU load and definitely more than all other programs.
I read it is some kind of programm for easy file sharing in local networks, so my question is if I can just disable it, when not needed or is it necessary for something I'm not aware of? It is working without error, but I want to save some battery..

Thanks!

Edit: I'm aware that 15% constant usage is not a lot, but is much more than other programs use most of the times. That's why the question is if this program which I'm not using needs to be running

[image]

Comment: 15% isn't anywhere *near* "High Usage" on an 8-core system.  What makes you think it's a 'high load'?

Comment: Sure, you are right. 15 was quiet low. Average was about 25. My point is, that it is "some" usage and maybe unnecessary.. Even 25 of one core is low, I get that

Comment: I would rewrite your quesiton then to ask if you need Avahi, rather than "Is this necessary it keeps using high cpu" (because it isn't)

Comment: Most of the time it has more CPU usage than all other programs combined which is relatively speaking "high" CPU usage for a program which has no apparent reason to run for me, because I'm not actively using it. I will rephrase my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable avahi-daemon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205937/how-can-i-disable-avahi-daemon)

Answer (score 0):

Avahi is a free, open-source implementation of the Zeroconf. It allows you to easily configure and connect to network services such as printers, scanners, and other devices, without having to manually configure the network settings.

You can disable the daemon with this command.

```
systemctl disable avahi-daemon
```