# Turn off printer discovery

Tags: networking, printing, 23.10

How can we turn off the automatic printer discovery in Ubuntu?

I already tried to turn it off in `/etc/cups/cups-browsed-conf` by setting:

```
BrowseRemoteProtocols none
BrowseLocalProtocols none
BrowseProtocols none
```

But this did not work. Printers are still being found automatically within the printer system settings window.

I have also tried to turn off `cups-browsed`:

```
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed
```

But this also did not work.

What must be done to keep Ubuntu quiet regarding network discovery for printers?

Comment: Is avahi on your system?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/205937/how-can-i-disable-avahi-daemon  is what you need to do